# when I convert string to integer using numpy genfromtxt function, why is it all 0 for what I want to convert

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I should get different number of different materials of wood. but I got 0 for all materials.

> %%writefile wood.txt

```
item,material,number

100,oak,33
110,maple,14
120,oak,7
145,birch,3


tree_to_int = dict(oak=1,maple=2,birch=3)

def convert(s):
    return tree_to_int.get(s,0)

data = np.genfromtxt('wood.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=np.int, 
names=True,converters={1:convert})
data
```

[output]:

```
array([(100, 0, 33), (110, 0, 14), (120, 0,  7), (145, 0,  3)],dtype=[('item', '<i4'), ('material', '<i4'), ('number', '<i4')])
```

Comment: In `convert()`, add `print(s)` so you can see the exact value being searched for.  I bet this will reveal the true problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's because the strings read from "wood.txt" are bytestrings. That's why they couldn't be found in the dictionary. To fix it, just decode the bytestings like below

```
def convert(s):
    return tree_to_int.get(s.decode("utf-8") , 0)
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use pandas

```
import pandas

tree_to_int = pandas.DataFrame([{'material': 'oak', 'material_int': 1}, {'material': 'maple', 'material_int': 2}, {'material': 'birch', 'material_int': 3}])

df = pandas.read_csv('wood.txt')

data = pandas.merge(df, tree_to_int, how='left', on='material')
```

Comment: I think that was the actual question -- why aren't oak/maple/etc. being converted to their values in the tree_to_int dict?